# SonarQube: Presentation of filename in widget measure filter as histogram

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web, sonarqube5.6

I'm using the Measure filter as histogram widget in my self-defined SonarQube dashboard. This widget shows to the resources and relevant to a metric the metric value of a resource. The Problem is, that the resourcename / the filename is not completely rendered. see the Image attached [Measure Filter as histogram view in dashboard to a specified measure filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrTSp.png) . Is there a possibiltity to completely render the filename. Is this behaviour a bug of the widget.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but there's no possibility to customize this widget to change the way the component path is displayed.